# On the nature of the force $F = \frac{mv^2}{r}$

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, centripetal-force

Suppose while solving some equation, I got 
$$F = \frac{mv^2}{r}.$$
Is it necessary that it is always the centripetal force with the particle undergoing circular motion?
Can this force be specifying something else?

Comment: If it's not centripetal force, what would you define $r$ as?

Comment: I was getting something like this, mv^2÷2 = Ax +C where A and C are constants, I am arbitrarily considering C as zero. Now I get two problems first A is an constant and mv^2/x is a force. Overall Equation mv^2/x =2A.

Comment: I think you should include details of what lead to your equation into your question. An equation by itself means nothing in physics. Also, I formatted your question using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Please do this for future edits and questions.

Comment: "Centripetal" is just the "catch-all" term for any force that is causing an object to move in a circular path.  I'm not trying to be pedantic, but in a sense, the answer to your questions is always "yes".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Such a force is not necessarily a centripetal force. For it to be a centripetal force it must also be pointed in a direction perpendicular to the velocity.

Indeed, provided $v\ne 0$, any force may be broken into vector components parallel and perpendicular to the velocity. Regardless of the size of the perpendicular component there is some $r$ for which $$F_{\perp}=\frac{mv^2}{r}$$